# Get the users who have downloaded the content document

Tags: apex, content

I can only find one document about the Content Objects
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_content.htm

I am able to see the users who have downloaded the document from the UI.

In my code, I want to get the users who downloaded a content document.
Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005326&language=en_US

Just by looking at the createdById you can get an idea of who downloaded the content

```
[SELECT 
    ContentDocumentId,
    CreatedById
FROM
    ContentVersionHistory
WHERE
    Field = 'contentVersionDownloaded'];
```