# Apex: How to write test code for processing read-only object?

Tags: apex

I'm querying records of an object called "ContentVersionHistory" in my code.

In my test method, I tried to create some test records of this object but I received error "DML operation INSERT not allowed on ContentVersionHistory".

I checked the document:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversionhistory.htm

It says:  Use this read-only object to query the history of a document version.

Then how can I test my code?

```
global class CE_GetMp4Attendees implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {    
    //Get the existing training session Names,IDs
    Map<String,CE_Training_Session__c> MapCETrainingSessions=new Map<String,CE_Training_Session__c>();
    List<CE_Training_Session__c> lsttrainingsThisQuarter = [select Id,Conf_Name__c from CE_Training_Session__c where Start_Time__c>:CE_Utilities.quarterStart];
    For(CE_Training_Session__c cts : lsttrainingsThisQuarter){
        MapCETrainingSessions.put(cts.Conf_Name__c,cts);
    }
    //key: CE Training sessionId
    //value: a set of userId
    Map<String,Set<String>> MapSessionUsers = new Map<String,Set<String>>();
    For(CE_Attendee_Infor__c cai : [select Attendee__c,CE_Training_Session__c from CE_Attendee_Infor__c where CE_Training_Session__c in :lsttrainingsThisQuarter ])
    {
        if(MapSessionUsers.containsKey(cai.CE_Training_Session__c)){
            MapSessionUsers.get(cai.CE_Training_Session__c).add(cai.Attendee__c);
        }
        else{
            MapSessionUsers.put(cai.CE_Training_Session__c,new Set<String>{cai.Attendee__c});
        }
    }
    //create a Map of contentversionId to CE training session Id
    //Get the contentversion Ids
    List<ContentVersion> lstContentVersions = [select Id,Title from ContentVersion where createddate > LAST_FISCAL_QUARTER and Title like 'CE Sales%'];
    Map<String,String> MapcontentversionCESession = new Map<String,String>();
    For(ContentVersion cv : lstContentVersions){

        String TruncatedTitle = cv.Title;
        if(cv.Title.indexOf('-')!=-1)
        {
            TruncatedTitle = cv.Title.substringBefore('-');
        }

        if(MapCETrainingSessions.containsKey(TruncatedTitle))
        {
            MapcontentversionCESession.put(cv.Id, MapCETrainingSessions.get(TruncatedTitle).Id);
        }
    }
    System.debug(MapcontentversionCESession);
    //get all the Mp4 attendees
    //Key: ID  Value:  Key: Email, Value: CE_Attendee_Infor__c
    Map<String,Map<String,CE_Attendee_Infor__c>> MapSessionMapAttendees = new Map<String,Map<String,CE_Attendee_Infor__c>>();
    For(String cvId : MapcontentversionCESession.keySet())
    {
        MapSessionMapAttendees.put(MapcontentversionCESession.get(cvId),new Map<String,CE_Attendee_Infor__c>());
        List<ContentVersionHistory> lstContentVersionHistory = [select CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedBy.Email from ContentVersionHistory where Field = 'contentVersionDownloaded' and ContentVersionId =: cvId];
        if(lstContentVersionHistory.size()>0){
            For(ContentVersionHistory cvh: lstContentVersionHistory){
                CE_Attendee_Infor__c info = new CE_Attendee_Infor__c(Attendee_Email__c = cvh.CreatedBy.Email,Attendee__c=cvh.CreatedById,Type_of_Attendence__c='Mp4',CE_Training_Session__c=MapcontentversionCESession.get(cvId));
                if(MapSessionUsers.containsKey(info.CE_Training_Session__c)&&!MapSessionUsers.get(info.CE_Training_Session__c).contains(info.Attendee__c)&&!MapSessionMapAttendees.get(info.CE_Training_Session__c).containsKey(info.Attendee_Email__c)) 
                {
                    MapSessionMapAttendees.get(info.CE_Training_Session__c).put(info.Attendee_Email__c,info);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    For(Map<String,CE_Attendee_Infor__c> mapAttendess : MapSessionMapAttendees.values()){
        insert(mapAttendess.values());
    }
}
}
```

This is the code I want to test:

```
List<ContentVersion> lstContentVersions = [select Id,Title from ContentVersion where createddate > LAST_FISCAL_QUARTER and Title like 'CE Sales%'];
For(String cvId : MapcontentversionCESession.keySet())
    {
List<ContentVersionHistory> lstContentVersionHistory = [select CreatedById,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedBy.Email from ContentVersionHistory where Field = 'contentVersionDownloaded' and ContentVersionId =: cvId];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this scenario in one of my tasks. What I did is move up the levels and what I mean by that is finding what dependency the ContentVersionHistory has to other objects.

I find out that all you have to do in your test is to create and insert a FeedItem with the ContentData populate with a blob. Salesforce will automatically populate the ContentDocument, ContentVersion and ContentDocumentHistory (if you will do an update in your test class of the file you've uploaded).

To find out how they relate to each other, I used workbench and inserted a file through chatter and then I queried for various salesforce ids. I've also found a diagram of the [content objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content).

Hope it helps

Comment: In my case, which object should I use to set the parentId for the FeedItem?

Comment: It depends on what object you have the custom code. If you have it for example on account, you need to create an accountfeed record, I believe the same applies for contact and case. If you have a custom you need to set the parentid to the of the record you previously inserted in the test. Have a look at standard objects with feed https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm

Comment: I'm not sure if my code has anything to do with Chatter.

Comment: Edit your question and share some code if you want, we might help you better

Comment: Maihi, I updated the question, thank you for your help.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to imagine your schema even with the code. Is a training session linked to any uploaded documents ? My advice is to create, with the Salesforce UI the various records for a valid scenario. Then query the objects using developer console or workbench from the link I provided in the answer and then try and see if you can mimic that in your test class.

Comment: The content document was uploaded as File. The training session is a stand alone custom object. So it can be ignored. I wanted to use the FeedItem but I don't know where to find the ParentId.

Comment: As the documentation says a contentdocument represents a document that has been uploaded to a library to salesforce or a file in chatter. My use case was with chatter but I don't think it applies to you. Have you tried inserting a document in your test class ? I think that the idea that you should take from this is once you insert the document, everything will be automatically populated.

Comment: In my case, ContentDocumentHistory stores the download history of the uploaded documents.(which user at what time downloaded the content) I doubt if this can be automatically created since no one  downloads the document.    http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85669/get-the-users-who-have-downloaded-the-content-document